# install ubuntu by default and lost all partitions and my data

Tags: data-recovery

i am new with Ubuntu. After installing Ubuntu the partitions merged and all my information was lost. How can I recover my data? I used easeus from bootable usb and it could find all my files with different size but after recovery they can not be open. my files is very important for me. so please guide me to recovery my lost data

Comment: EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard can not run on a Linux computer so issues related to that seem not for us to address: it is basically a windows tools that can scan linux partitions. Maybe try with testdisk?   "my files is very important for me" Then you made backups. Restore from the last one you made.

Comment: Difficult issue. They could not be opened because of some of them could be fragmented. I empathize your grief.

Comment: Please always specify the edition of Ubuntu and its release number. Please add that to your question by clicking [edit].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i could recovery my data. at first eject hard disk then use it as external H.D.D then use Easeus partition recovery. I could recovery my lost files.